# Strategy for sending async emails in a sync method in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm looking for help on the strategy for sending emails after a student has registered for an event/class. The registering occurs in a synchronous method called from my controller but after I've registered (added the row to the db) for that event I am sending out an email. Sendgrid sends this email out from a async method and I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is? I have spinners and other items on the screen to inform the user that the process of registering is complete, do I make the entire call to regsiter async or is there a better way? Ideally I would like to keep the method 'SaveYogaSpaceEvent' sync and just make the sending of the email async.

Here is my code

Here is the method in my controller that registers the student.

```
Tuple<int, string, string, string> eventResults = _yogaSpaceService.SaveYogaSpaceEvent(User.Identity.GetUserId(), details);
```

Here is the method

```
internal Tuple<int, string, string, string> SaveYogaSpaceEvent(string userId, EventDetails details)
    { 
        // register in the db
        // do some other stuff
        // create email templates
        // send emails
        _emailService.SendEmail(new IdentityMessage { Destination = yogaProfile.ApplicationUser.Email, Subject = eventEmail.Item1, Body = eventEmail.Item2 }, eventEmail.Item3);
    }
```

Here is what the 'sendemail' method look like

```
public void SendEmail(IdentityMessage message, List<Attachment> attachments)
{
    ConfigSendGridAsync(message, attachments);
}

private async void ConfigSendGridAsync(IdentityMessage message, List<Attachment> attachments)
    {
        // configure the client 
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, emailAddresses, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
    }
```

Comment: How about making controller action method async  ? async all the way ?

Comment: Please show your complete controller code (all methods that are relevant).

Comment: You need to `await` the async method.  As a by product, the requirement that the methods be `async` will bubble up.

Comment: Shyju: But should I make the entire method async? Do I want to have the user sit and wait for the email to be sent, what if it takes a while!!? Wouldn't it be better to keep the register method sync and then make just the sending of the email async?

Comment: Ideally, you would not do that, you would basically send a message to some sort of a queue and the queue messages will be processed by some other process (lets say a windows service) and send the email. In this case, your web app made sure that it initiated the procedure to send an email (by successfully sending the message to the queue) so that it can return immediately. This ensures fault tolerance. If you do not care about that and want a very simply solution, you can spin up another thread to run the code which sends email

Comment: Shyju: essentially the sendgrid call is a queue of some sorts. I don't need to return anything from the email sending unless it fails. In which case I will log it.